# Rails can't find public system files through shared folder through virtualbox

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox, ruby-on-rails

I've just set-up a new dev environment where I have a win 7 host and ubuntu running in virtual box.

My rails application files are on the host system, and I shared the folder with the guest, and I run the rails server on the guest and connect to it through the host via guest IP address `http://10.1.1.10:3000`. I can load up web pages in a host browser which are being run from the guest web server. All that is going great.

The guest views the host files in the directory

`/media/sf_Ruby192/test_app/app`.

When attempting to open a file through rails via

`/media/sf_Ruby192/test_app/public/system/datasets/80/original/Full 2011_07_12_10_CSV.csv`,

I get a file not found error. When I attempt to open the file in the host browser via the guest web server at

`10.1.1.10:3000/public/system/datasets/80/original/Full%202011_07_12_10_CSV.csv`,

the server gets the page no problem.

Is there a routing problem with rails that I should be looking at? Or is this a virtualbox issue?

I'd normally post this to StackOverflow, but thought I'd likely be recommended to post this here.

Comment: What code are you using to open the file from Rails?